# How to make LLVM's `opt` command optimize builtin functions?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

Consider the following C program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int * ptr = malloc(8);
    *ptr = 14;
    return 4;
}
```

Compiling with `clang -S -emit-llvm -O1` [emits the following](https://godbolt.org/z/1xhcnY):

```
...
; Function Attrs: norecurse nounwind readnone uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !7 {
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32* undef, metadata !13, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !15
  ret i32 4, !dbg !16
}
...
```

The call to `malloc` is gone because it is a builtin function that `clang` knows about.
If we run `clang -S -emit-llvm -O1 -fno-builtin` instead we [get the following](https://godbolt.org/z/4defdh):

```
...
; Function Attrs: nounwind uwtable
define dso_local i32 @main() local_unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !14 {
  %1 = call noalias i8* @malloc(i64 8) #3, !dbg !22
  %2 = bitcast i8* %1 to i32*, !dbg !22
  call void @llvm.dbg.value(metadata i32* %2, metadata !20, metadata !DIExpression()), !dbg !23
  store i32 14, i32* %2, align 4, !dbg !24, !tbaa !25
  ret i32 4, !dbg !29
}
...
```

`clang` can't know what `malloc` is and has to leave the call in.

How can I get from the second LLVM program to the first using LLVM's `opt` command? How do I tell `opt` to use the knowledge about builtin functions that `clang` apparently has?

Comment: You have to run the right pass. The -print-after-all option prints the IR after each pass; you can study the output and find out which pass makes the difference in clang, then run that pass using opt.

Comment: Thank you, the call to `malloc` is removed by an ordinary `InstCombine` pass. Printing which passes are done with `-debug-pass=Arguments` gives exactly the same output with or without `-fno-builtin`.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific example, the problem is that `clang -fno-builtin` will produce LLVM code that explicitly marks calls to builtin functions with `nobuiltin`, i.e. `attributes #3 = { nobuiltin nounwind "no-builtins" }`.

Generally, which builtin functions are available is guessed by pass `-targetlibinfo`. You have to be careful to declare and use builtin functions at exactly the correct parameter and return types or LLVM will (correctly) not recognize them as builtins.